# GPS Location not get the data after add a function to check if gps is open or not

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I have a simple class to get the current location of the user it was working with no problem.
after i add a new function before I start get the user current location to check if GPS is open or not, if not opened it take the user to the setting file to open the GPS and then start take his location now I wait very long time and no location comes out. here is the code i use to get the current Location.
SingleShotLocationProvider

```
public class SingleShotLocationProvider {

    public static interface LocationCallback {
        public void onNewLocationAvailable(GPSCoordinates location);
    }
    public static boolean GPSOpen = false;
    public static boolean NetworkOpen = false;

    // calls back to calling thread, note this is for low grain: if you want higher precision, swap the
    // contents of the else and if. Also be sure to check gps permission/settings are allowed.
    // call usually takes <10ms
    public static void requestSingleUpdate(final Context context, final LocationCallback callback) {
        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        NetworkOpen = isNetworkEnabled;
        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            Log.i("NETWORK_OPEN", "YES NETWORK Open");
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                }

                @Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
                @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }
                @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }
            }, null);
        } else {
            boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            GPSOpen = isGPSEnabled;
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                Log.i("GPS_OPEN", "YES GPS Opened");
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                    }

                    @Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
                    @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }
                    @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }
                }, null);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please Open GPS and retry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MainWindow w = (MainWindow)context;
                w.DisableTheProgressGPSClosed(); // i have a simple progress bar wait until the app get the location then it GONE
            }
        }
    }


    // consider returning Location instead of this dummy wrapper class
    public static class GPSCoordinates {
        public float longitude = -1;
        public float latitude = -1;

        public GPSCoordinates(float theLatitude, float theLongitude) {
            longitude = theLongitude;
            latitude = theLatitude;
        }

        public GPSCoordinates(double theLatitude, double theLongitude) {
            longitude = (float) theLongitude;
            latitude = (float) theLatitude;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the function I use to check the GPS open or not.

```
public boolean turnGPSOn()
{
    LocationManager L = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (!L.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please open GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent I = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(I);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

here how I use it when the user click the button.

```
public void GetLocation() {
    if (turnGPSOn()) {
        return;
    }
    Log.i("Process_GPS_DATA", "Done process now GPS");
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    foo(this);
}
```

foo function which call the GPS class here.

```
public void foo(final Context context) {
    // when you need location
    // if inside activity context = this;
    SingleShotLocationProvider.requestSingleUpdate(context,
            new SingleShotLocationProvider.LocationCallback() {
                @Override public void onNewLocationAvailable(SingleShotLocationProvider.GPSCoordinates location) {
                    Log.i("Location", "my location is " + location.latitude + "," + location.longitude);
                    String BaseLocation = "https://www.google.com/maps/?q=" + location.latitude + "," + location.longitude + "";
                    StartSendRequest(location.longitude, location.latitude, BaseLocation);
                    Log.i("Google_URL", BaseLocation);
                }
            });
}
```

the problem is everything works fine but I wait a long time and no location are show I don't know why this problem, when i make a test I close the android GPS and then make the test no location are provided I test the same class before add check part and it worked fine.
when i test in emulator with already open GPS it worked and give me a location when i close GPS and then test again it not worked and I wait for long time and nothing show so what I did wrong.

Comment: This is the old way to check GPS and get location. Instead of you should use `FusedLocationProviderAPI`.

Comment: so that is why it did not give me the location? i feel its by luck sometimes it worked and sometimes not

Comment: Fused location provider API will give you accurate location.